# I need help to read and understand the record

Tags: death-records

I was using the **Findmypast** genealogy website and found an interesting record that could possibly mention one of my ancestors.

The name of the person that I am researching is **Ahmed Alla Khan**.

I need help **reading** and **understanding** the following **information** about him:

Ship Name, Ship Official Number, Ship Port of Registry, Date of Death, Place of Death, Christian Name, Surname, Sex, Age, Rank, Profession, or Occupation, Nationality, or Birthplace, Last Place of Abode and Cause of Death.

[image: Register of Deceased Passenger April, 1904]

Comment: Hi, what part are you having trouble with: seeing the image (visual impairment), reading the handwriting, understanding what it means?

Comment: Hi, I was having a problem reading—mainly Rank, Profession, or Occupation and Last Place of Abode and Cause of Death.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  When you need help with a record, please post the archive reference and/or the database the record comes from and not just the image itself.  Knowing which agency created a record is important when you are trying to understand a record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The details for that entry are as follows:

- Ship Name: **Mozaffari**
- Official Number: **53543**
- Port of Registry: **Bombay**
- Date of Death: **11 April 1904**
- Place of Death: **At Sea**
- Christian Name:  **Ahmed Alla**
- Surname:  **Khan**
- Sex:  **Male**
- Age:  **72**
- Rank, Profession, or Occupation: **Hajee**  (Presumably [Hajii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajji))
- Nationality, or Birthplace:  **Mohamedan** [sic]  (i.e. Muslim)
- Last Place of Abode: **Ship**
- Cause of Death:  **Old age and general debility**

---

I did find a [PDF copy of the record of the Court of Inquiry](https://plimsoll.southampton.gov.uk/SOTON_Documents/Plimsoll/19807.pdf) into the loss of the Mozaffari at the port of Ibo in 1910, which includes more details about the vessel itself.  Further details may be found in the Lloyds Register of Shipping, and the [1904 volume](https://archive.org/details/HECROS1904ST/page/n573/mode/2up) is available on Internet Archive.

---

You may be able to find more about Ahmed Alla Khan in the passenger list - if it survives, and if you can locate it.  As a starting point I would try to find a copy of *[Lloyds List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_List)* for 1904 to try and determine details of the voyage.  This will probably involve quite a bit of searching to find the correct issue.  Hopefully you'll then have an indication of where any crew and passenger lists are held (if they survive).

Comment: Thank you very much!
What country or nationality is Mohamedan?
I searched on Google, but I could not seem to find an answer.

Comment: @Umk It seems to be just a mis-spelling of "Mohammedan", and was an alternative term for "Muslim".

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. I was trying to find his nationality or birthplace, but it seems that I would not be able to find it.

Comment: @Umk That information may be in the original passenger list if you can locate it (and if it survives).

Comment: Ah, yes. I will look for it. Thank you a lot for all your help.

Comment: Looking at the IA link... Why is the Lloyds [presumably "of London"] Register written in French and not English?

Comment: The WP article about the [_Mozaffari_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_vessel_Mozaffari) contains a sourced statement that might be relevant, given the date of Ahmed Alla Khan's death: "In April 1904, Mozaffari was used in an operation to hoist Persian flag at Abu Musa and Tunbs after removing those of Sharjah." You would want to track down the source, which is a book: Mojtahed-Zadeh, Pirouz (2013). Security and Territoriality in the Persian Gulf: A Maritime Political Geography. Routledge. p. 196. ISBN 9781136817243

Comment: @shoover  That is a different vessel.  The official number listed in this register matches the SS Mozaffari.  See the links to the court of inquiry into the loss of the vessel and the 1904 Lloyds Register of Shipping for more.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Ah, thanks! But why is the Lloyds Register in French?!

Comment: @shoover I think they published in English and French.  The one I found on Internet Archive happens to be in French.